# iPhone not loading other css

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone

I don't know much about webdesign and I am now trying to make iPhones load another CSS than desktops. Been trying for 4 hours now and I am falling into a deep depression now. All I do is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
  href="iphone.css"
   media="only screen and (max-device-width: 
  480px)" /> 

<link href="styleT.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

`iphone.css` doesn't even exist but iPhones keep loading `styleT.css`

What can I do? Desktops load the styleT.css perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

I messed up the order of the styles. I did it the other way around before, but forgot the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` (had it in there before but then somehow commented it out)

I am so happy I am a programmer and not a web dev I couldn't have the patience for stuff like this